# Dovecot - login_greeting new line character

Tags: dovecot

I am using this `login_greeting` for IMAP(S) protocol:

```
protocol imap {
  login_greeting = "mail.domain.eu -------> \"WELCOME TO PORT 993!\""
}
```

I want to know if it's possible to add a new line character at the beginning of the string? This doesn't work:

```
protocol imap {
  login_greeting = "\nmail.domain.eu -------> \"WELCOME TO PORT 993!\""
}
```

And this reports an error because it looks like configuration parameters have to be in one line:

```
protocol imap {
  login_greeting = "
  mail.domain.eu -------> \"WELCOME TO PORT 993!\""
}
```

Any other idea?

Comment: Are you trying to break the protocol and make it impossible for anyone to communicate with you?

Comment: Would a newline mean that?

Comment: Of course. That's how lines are delimited!

Comment: Then probably this question has no answer.

Comment: Why are you thinking about doing this?

Comment: Only to format the output nicely. It is purely estetic reason.

Comment: Don't bother. Humans don't see this.